# Unable to resolve dependency for org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am new to annotation based programming and don't know what maven artifact to add to my pom.xml for **org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional**, I googled(like first 5 pages of search results) but unable to find what am i looking for. I am using spring 3. Also if there is any online tutorial  to know more about annotations in spring. thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's in [spring-tx](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx).

The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html) covers Spring quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

A special case for the former answer. If you use mybatis and maven,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

would import spring-tx package for you as:

```
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
```