# Idea cannot resolve @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

Idea only finding @Transactional in Spring 2.5.6 and importing such dependency with Maven however I use everywhere the 4x version which is causing problems

Comment: Spring 2.5.6 is very very old, dont use it. Use 4.X version...

Comment: Did you add, on your classpath, the jar spring-tx? In spring 4 they divided the modules

Comment: Found solution, in case someone has similar problem
here is the [link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702364/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-org-springframework-transaction-annotation-tran

Answer (score 0):

1. Hover over "@Transactional" and click "Add Maven Dependency..."
2. Go to the "Search For Artifact" window and search for "org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional"
3. Search through the results and select "org.springframework:spring-tx:4.2.5.RELEASE" (this is the version recommended to me by Idea as of today)
4. Press "add" and stand on top of "@Transactional" again, now you can choose "Import Class" and with this it is solved.

In the pom.xml file the following should appear:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```