# Transactional cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am using `Spring + Hibernate` and getting;

> `Transactional cannot be resolved to a type error.`

I have added the following dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing any dependencies? How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add spring transaction for that add following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For reference you can visit this link

[Unable to resolve dependency for org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702364/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-org-springframework-transaction-annotation-tran)

Answer (score 1):

You want to depend on [spring-tx](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-tx%22)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```